# OWASP Pentest - "Sensitive data sent in clear text"

Tags: tls, authentication, passwords, web-application, rest

We have our web app / REST API getting tested by potential customer. In the report they came up with this issue:

> Sensitive data like user credentials on login page, password reset,
> change password etc. are sent in clear text format. If sent in clear
> text format attacker can steal those from the browsers memory.

And I am wondering whether it is time to dispute this as - obviously, since this is year 2021 - the connection is over HTTPS. They can see the credentials in the network tab of the browser console but it is the same bloody password they entered one sec ago and sent.

The recommendation is:

> It is recommended to use hashing to send the credentials over the
> network. Strong hashing like SHA-256 should be used.

It seems like some dated info or test method used from the old days when https was rare.

As security professionals - what would you recommend? Should we cope with the requirement or should we dispute that it is unnecessary layer over HTTPS that is in place?

I am aware of questions (*) dealing with the topic itself and I am also aware that this might lead to opinionated answers. Still trying my luck as it seems a bit over the top. Thx.

(*)

- [I just send username and password over https. Is this ok?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7057/i-just-send-username-and-password-over-https-is-this-ok)
- [https security - should password be hashed server-side or client-side?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/https-security-should-password-be-hashed-server-side-or-client-side)
- [Is it ok to send plain-text password over HTTPS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110415/is-it-ok-to-send-plain-text-password-over-https)

Comment: What's your question? You already have our technical recommendations in those other questions. If your question is client management, that's not a security concern. I'd get them to see if their google password is sent in clear text...

Comment: "It is recommended to use" -- simple, get them to cite the source of the recommendation

Comment: @schroeder yes, my question was "client management" one. Since we are dealing with this sort of external testing for the first time, I wanted to ask the (pro) community what is common practice in such case... Whether you bow your had and get back to keyboard or whether it is OK to say "hold your horses". Got my answers, thx to both of you guys. It is kinda pity the question is closed but hey, I'm new here :)

Comment: Your hunch is absolutely correct, and you linked all the relevant questions. The problem of insecure data transport is addressed with HTTPS. If that's up correctly, you don't need to be be concerned about secure data exchange between client and server. (Securely *storing* secrets would be a different story, as you certainly know.) Also, welcome!

Comment: @Arminius thx. We are storing credentials on the server hashed by [bcrypt.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js), I think that should be fine.

Comment: What they recommend is a well known anti-pattern CWE-836: Use of Password Hash Instead of Password for Authentication (https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/836.html), exposing you to 
CAPEC-644: Use of Captured Hashes (Pass The Hash) (http://capec.mitre.org/data/definitions/644.html). Whoever is testing isn't or shouldn't be a security professional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is obvious malarkey, and whoever wrote that report has no idea what they are doing.**

As all the linked answers state, it is perfectly fine to send plain passwords over TLS. I strongly suspect that whoever wrote this "recommendation" mixed up *"Don't send passwords over plaintext"* with *"Don't store passwords in plain text."*

But better than disputing their finding would be to ask them to actually attack your system and demonstrate how it supposedly is vulnerable. Since it's not, they'll have to admit that it's secure.

Comment: I disagree. Anyone on that system can see that password come in. It is not malarkey. Passwords should always be hashed client-side before being sent over any network, encrypted or not.

Comment: @8vtwo please have a look at the linked questions. If you send the hash, then the hash becomes the password, which means "Anyone on that system can see that password come in."  Please provide an example of a major site that hashes passwords before sending over TLS. Or is this just your personal preference?

Comment: @8vtwo This is simply wrong. No major website implements that, no security professional recommends that.

Comment: @8vtwo Congratulations you just made the system vulnerable to "pass the hash" attacks. Did you work at Microsoft in the nineties?