# How authenticate a login with javascript

Tags: javascript, hmac, bcrypt

I want to authenticate a user using a username and password in a web app running javascript interfacing to a non node js or php  server. In a normal desktop app I could use bcrypt or an hmac or ??. When I search the internet I come up with ambiguous results for HMAC and Javascript or Bcrypt and Javascript.
Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve by hashing the password on the client-side, but see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/https-security-should-password-be-hashed-server-side-or-client-side for why this is almost always a bad idea.  Unless you are trying to implement some sort of PAKE or SRP scheme, you probably should be hashing the password on the server side.  If it's a static site, then use basic HTTP authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Passwords should be hashed server-side, so you should search for `php +bcrypt` or `nodejs +bcrypt` (HMAC is not good for password hashing), not `JavaScript +bcrypt`. For PHP, you'd use `password_hash`, for nodejs there are bcrypt libraries available.