# SHA256 Encrypting with Value

Tags: encryption, sha256

Is it possible to encrypt a value (such as "hello world") with itself ("hello world") using an encrypting technique such as SHA256? Is that safe to do or would it be easily compromised?

Comment: SHA256 is a hash algorithm, not an encryption algorithm. It's not even _possible_ to do this as SHA256 doesn't use a key.

Comment: I also don't understand the point... "I'm going to send you a secret message, but in order to open it, you have to already know what it is". What's the bigger goal you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Encrypting something with itself as the key is [sometimes suggested](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/10476) as a home-made hashing solution, so if that's what you're after there's an answer for you (and that answer is don't do it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to encrypt a value (such as "hello world") with itself ("hello world") [...]

Is it *possible*, but not recommended in practice (see below).

> using an encrypting technique such as SHA256?

No, SHA256 is not an encryption algorithm. SHA256 is used for hashing. Maybe you meant to write AES256 rather than SHA256?

> Is that safe to do or would it be easily compromised?

It's not safe to do in a practical way since you would need to retain the key to decrypt the data, but since the key *is* the data in your proposed scheme that would mean that this proposed encryption scheme completely defeats its own purpose!