# What is the meaning of 'adaptative' and 'over time it can be made slower' in the context of the bcrypt algorithm?

Tags: hash, bcrypt

I'm reading the wikipedia definition about [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) but I don't understand the meaning of 'adaptative' and 'over time it can be made slower'. Can someone explain what they mean in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the inputs to the bcrypt algorithm is the number of rekeying rounds that will be used when calculating the hash. As time passes, and the CPU power available to potential attackers increases, you can simply increase this parameter to keep up -- you'll have to find some way to re-hash all of your old stored passwords, of course.

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/is-it-possible-to-increase-the-cost-of-bcrypt-or-pbkdf2-when-its-already-calcula