# Recomended hash algorithm

Tags: hash, bcrypt, pbkdf2, scrypt, sha2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)
>   [Do any security experts recommend bcrypt for password storage?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage)

What would you choose between:

- PBKDF2 SHA256 (270,000 iterations)
- bcrypt (12, 13 or 14 cost: 1-2 seconds)
- scrypt: I don't know if my hosting will allow it

I have to choose an algorithm to store passwords in a MySQL DB.

I've just read that bcrypt isn't so secure, PBKDF2 is more tested (but it could be reasonably faster on GPU/FPGA), scrypt is too new (and not tested enough) but is almost unbreakable.

So, please give me advice (in regards a sensible data website) and explain me what is better and why.

Comment: What are your security requirements? Why are you using a hash algorithm?

Comment: @GdD ops, sorry.. I forgot it!

Comment: A work factor that leads to 1 sec verification time opens you up to trivial DoS attacks.

Comment: @CodesInChaos and if I set up sleep function based on requests made?