# Basic question regarding OpenSSL and AES-GCM

Tags: tls, openssl, aes

While researching how to encrypt private keys for SSH connections as securely as possible, I have run into the following very basic understanding problems (Note: I have used the newest stable release 1.0.2h of OpenSSL for my research):

1. [`man enc`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/enc.html) states that the enc utility does not support authenticated encryption modes like GCM. On the other hand, I am using TLS 1.2 ciphers like ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 on my web server which uses OpenSSL for encrypting connections, and I have checked that those ciphers indeed are negotiated when connecting via SSL / TLS to the respective web site.

   So OpenSSL obviously is able to encrypt data in AESxxx-GCM mode. I would have expected that OpenSSL uses the same code to encrypt data when called via `openssl enc` as it uses to encrypt data while providing SSL / TLS functionality to web servers.

   Did I misunderstand something? What's the reason that OpenSSL supports AESxxx-GCM while doing TLS / SSL, but can't encrypt data directly that way when called via command line?
2. A common method to view the available cipher names (not cipher suites) is to call `openssl enc` with a wrong parameter, e.g. `openssl enc --help`. This makes openssl print a short help, including the available cipher names. In my case, the output includes multiple AES-GCM ciphers. Why does `openssl enc` claim to support those ciphers while the respective man page claims it does not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenSSL implements almost a dozen symmetric ciphers, and several dozen cipher-mode combinations, but provides a (nearly) **single interface** to all of them **in the EVP module** (i.e. external function and type names beginning `EVP_`) [documented here online](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_CipherInit.html) or in the (crosslinked) man page for `EVP_{Cipher,Encrypt,Decrypt}*` and `EVP_CIPHER_*` and `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_*` on any Unixy system with OpenSSL installed. (If you built/installed it yourself rather than using the package manager or equivalent for your OS or distro, you may need to use MANPATH or other `man` options to find the man pages.) Similarly numerous digest/hash algorithms and public-key (and hybrid) encryption and signature algorithms are accessed through generic interfaces; [see man evp](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/evp.html). But the **AEAD modes** (GCM and CCM, plus OCB planned in 1.1.0) do not exactly fit the generic API and **require additional** 'control' calls, see the sections 'GCM and OCB modes' and 'CCM mode' in the above man page.

The SSL-and-TLS module (top-level directory `ssl/` in the source) contains code in `t1_enc.c` that does different `EVP` calls for (implemented) AEAD suites, in the same way it also handles variations for CBC and stream ciphers, obsolete but still coded 'export' ciphers, TLS1.1 vs earlier IV handling, and other protocol options and variations.

But commandline `enc` in `apps/enc.c` only uses the generic interface and not the AEAD specials, although there is [an unassigned entry in the request tracker (login guest/guest)](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=4228) to add this. The commandline utilities in general are fairly minimal wrappers around functionality in libssl and libcrypto, and if you want something complete, polished, convenient, etc. the idea is you should either modify or replace them.
For this case you (would) need to define how the tag, and possibly AAD, is handled in the ciphertext file format, which is currently simple to the point of being trivial -- and remember any change that doesn't work with the probably millions of `enc` files users have stored over the past two decades won't be accepted by anyone but you. (update) The bugtracker moved to https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/471 where it is 'resolved' in 1.1.1 -- by documenting that `enc` does not and will not support AEAD. Also note that the early 1.0.1 releases, through patch g (2012-03 to 2014-04) failed to give an error message for this case; you could run the `enc` command with a GCM or CCM cipher, but it discarded the tag on encryption and gave an error on decryption.

Remember also that `enc` with a password (not actual key and IV using `-K` uppercase and `-iv`) uses a **very poor PBKDF**, a variant of PBKDF1 [see EVP_BytesToKey](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) with **only one iteration**.
See 
[openssl: recover key and IV by passphrase](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/openssl-recover-key-and-iv-by-passphrase)
and [openssl enc uses md5 to hash the password and the salt](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79913/openssl-enc-uses-md5-to-hash-the-password-and-the-salt)
and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/35614/12642 (disclosure: mine). 
Worrying about using best-practice ciphers like AES256-GCM with this PBKDF is like the proverbial gilding a cow turd.

The usage message for `openssl enc -invalid` lists all symmetric ciphers/modes in EVP, even those `enc` doesn't support. If you care, you could report this as a bug. `openssl list-cipher-algorithms` (planned space instead of first hyphen in 1.1.0) does the same, but `openssl list-cipher-commands` (ditto) lists only those usable as commands, which excludes the AEAD ones. (updates) In 1.1.0+ all command parsing is rewritten and the usage messages are replaced by `-help` which for `enc` does not list ciphers; the explicit commands are now `list -cipher-{algorithms,commands}` i.e. space *and* hyphen.

Finally, you mention but don't actually ask about SSH. If you mean **OpenSSH** (which is not the only SSH), FYI OpenSSH before 6.5 `ssh-keygen` actually uses OpenSSL libcrypto to *write* privatekeys in OpenSSL's 'legacy' formats (PEM types `RSA PRIVATE KEY`, `DSA PRIVATE KEY`, `EC PRIVATE KEY`) which also use `EVP_BytesToKey` with one iteration. But `ssh-keygen` and `ssh` and `sshd` using OpenSSL *read* routines can also handle OpenSSL's 'new' (circa 2000?) PKCS#8-encrypted format, PEM type `ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY`, which can use PBKDF2 with 2048 iterations through 1.0.2 (good around 2000, barely adequate now) and planned configurable up to INT_MAX in 1.1.0. OpenSSH beginning 6.5 (2014-01) has an option `-o` for its own (non-ASN.1 but still PEM) format using bcrypt, and forces that option for key type ed25519 (which OpenSSL doesn't support, at least not yet). (updates) OpenSSL 1.1.0 (2016-08) did add `-iter N` and optional `-scrypt*` for PKCS8 as expected; OTOH OpenSSH 7.8 (2018-08) made its own 'new format' the default; `-o` is no longer needed, and if you want to get the old and bad legacy formats you use `-m pem`.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation of the relationship between `openssl enc` and the actual functions in the library. So I must write my own utility if I have to encrypt something using AESxxx-GCM.

Comment: Regarding OpenSSH: Before asking, I had read about `ssk-keygen -o`, the new format and the new PBKDF (which gains its strength mainly from its slowness). Actually, my motivation to ask was to combine OpenSSH's new PBKDF with AES256-GCM for encrypting the private keys (`ssh-keygen -o` seems to use AES128-GCM). So my next question would have been how to plug in another PBKDF into OpenSSL ... but I first wanted to understand the issues with `openssl enc`.

Comment: A last comment: OpenSSL has a good reputation IMHO, so I am quite disappointed that it doesn't warn its users about the weak PBDKF and that it doesn't provide a reasonable one. There is nothing in the manuals regarding the PBKDF, and I don't want to know how many millions of users have encrypted their private keys using OpenSSL, not being aware that this sort of encryption is worth nothing.

Comment: @Binarus (0) OpenSSH 6.5 to 7.2 (at least the 'p' tarballs I have) `ssh-keygen -o` (or ed25519) defaults to (bcrypt plus) aes256-cbc, not aes128-gcm, but you can override with `-Z aes{128,256}-gcm@openssh.com` (undocumented AFAICS).

Comment: (1) *For privatekeys* it isn't loud but OpenSSL manpage for `PEM_{read,write}{,_bio}_{manythings}` in NOTES says "The old PrivateKey routines are retained for compatibility. New applications should [use PKCS8] because ... more secure (they use an iteration count of 2048 whereas the traditional routines use a count of 1) ...." and just after that in PEM ENCRYPTION FORMAT "The old PrivateKey routines ... [use] EVP_BytesToKey [with salt and] an iteration count of 1 ...." -- and this gist (though not exact wording) goes back to at least 0.9.8m in 2010, the earliest I can easily check.

Comment: For `enc` on the other hand, no such warning (or even detail) I've noticed. Oh, and yes OpenSSH `cipher.c` does do the extra 'control' calls needed for GCM -- in routines that are used both for comms and for new-format privatekey files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information regarding `ssh-keygen -o` and its undocumented features. Regarding the PBKDF, as far as I have understood, even 2048 rounds are unsafe if the hashing function can be computed extremely fast, like MD5 or SHA1 (I have read that a single consumer GPU can compute about 1 billion hashed per second for such functions). So I think OpenSSL can solve the problem only by using other PBKDFs which are very slow by design, for example bcrypt (like `ssh-keygen -o`).

Comment: Which is presumably why 1.1.0 plans to allow higher iterations -- at least for now created only from commandline not PEM_write, but it appears library (and thus OpenSSH) can _read_ it. TTBOMK bcrypt is stronger against GPU, but not FPGA; scrypt is probably better if the attacker is willing to spend a little money, but has less history and may still be vulnerable to ASIC. FWIW OpenSSL 1.1.0 plans to add support for scrypt (again created from commandline only for now). OTOH now that Argon2 has been semiofficially semistandardized, maybe it should be used instead?

Comment: Additional aspect: AFAIK, Putty is the most widely used SSH client for Windows. Unfortunately, it uses its own private key format. The developers provide a utility which reads keys which have been generated using `ssh-keygen -o` and converts them to Putty's format. The initial strong encryption of those keys will be lost by converting them (e.g. due to the utility's weak PBKDF). I hope the developers will provide a reasonable method for securely encrypting the private keys in the future (or, better, allow direct usage of *unaltered* keys which have been generated by `ssh-keygen`).

Answer (score 4):

Because until now, `openssl enc` does not support AES-256-GCM, I've written the following C source code to do what `openssl enc` would do:

(compile this way `gcc -Wall -lcrypto -o aes256gcm aes256gcm.c`)

```
// AES-256-GCM with libcrypto
// gcc -Wall -lcrypto -o aes256gcm aes256gcm.c

// tag is 16 bytes long
// no AAD (Additional Associated Data)
// output format: tag is written just after cipher text (see RFC-5116, sections 5.1 and 5.2)

// KEY=a6a7ee7abe681c9c4cede8e3366a9ded96b92668ea5e26a31a4b0856341ed224
// IV=87b7225d16ea2ae1f41d0b13fdce9bba
// echo -n 'plain text' | ./aes256gcm $KEY $IV | od -t x1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = NULL;
unsigned char *iv = NULL;
unsigned char *buf_plain = NULL;
unsigned char *buf_cipher = NULL;

typedef enum { false, true } bool;

void freeCrypto() {
  if (ctx) {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    ctx = NULL;
  }
  CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
  ERR_free_strings();

  if (iv) {
    free(iv);
    iv = NULL;
  }
  if (buf_plain) {
    free(buf_plain);
    buf_plain = NULL;
  }
  if (buf_cipher) {
    free(buf_cipher);
    buf_cipher = NULL;
  }
}

void handleCryptoError() {
  fprintf(stderr, "ERROR\n");
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  freeCrypto();
  exit(1);
}

bool isValidHexChar(char c) {
  return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}

unsigned char hex2uchar(char *hex) {
  unsigned char ret;

  if (hex[0] >= 'a' && hex[0] <= 'f') ret = (hex[0] - 'a' + 10) * 16;
  else ret = (hex[0] - '0') * 16;
  if (hex[1] >= 'a' && hex[1] <= 'f') ret += hex[1] - 'a' + 10;
  else ret += hex[1] - '0';
  return ret;
}

int main(int ac, char **av, char **ae)
{
  const EVP_CIPHER *cipher;
  unsigned char key[32];
  int iv_len, len, i;
  unsigned char tag[16];

  if (ac != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s KEY IV\n", av[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  char *key_txt = av[1];
  char *iv_txt = av[2];

  ERR_load_crypto_strings();

  if (strlen(key_txt) != 2 * sizeof key) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid key size\n");
    freeCrypto();
    return 1;
  }

  if (strlen(iv_txt) < 2 || strlen(iv_txt) % 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid IV size\n");
    freeCrypto();
    return 1;
  }
  iv_len = strlen(iv_txt) / 2;

  if (!(iv = malloc(iv_len))) {
    perror("malloc");
    freeCrypto();
    return 1;
  }

  if (!(buf_plain = malloc(iv_len))) {
    perror("malloc");
    freeCrypto();
    return 1;
  }

  if (!(buf_cipher = malloc(iv_len))) {
    perror("malloc");
    freeCrypto();
    return 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof key; i++) {
    if (!isValidHexChar(key_txt[2*i]) || !isValidHexChar(key_txt[2*i+1])) handleCryptoError();
    key[i] = hex2uchar(key_txt + 2*i);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < iv_len; i++) {
    if (!isValidHexChar(iv_txt[2*i]) || !isValidHexChar(iv_txt[2*i+1])) handleCryptoError();
    iv[i] = hex2uchar(iv_txt + 2*i);
  }

  if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleCryptoError();
  if (!(cipher = EVP_aes_256_gcm())) handleCryptoError();
  if (1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, cipher, NULL, NULL, NULL)) handleCryptoError();
  if (1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, iv_len, NULL)) handleCryptoError();
  if (1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv)) handleCryptoError();

  do {
    size_t ret = fread(buf_plain, 1, iv_len, stdin);
    if (!ret) {
      if (ferror(stdin)) {
    perror("fread");
        freeCrypto();
        return 1;
      }
      if (feof(stdin)) break;
    }

    if (1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, buf_cipher, &len, buf_plain, ret)) handleCryptoError();

    if (len && !fwrite(buf_cipher, len, 1, stdout)) {
      if (feof(stderr)) fprintf(stderr, "EOF on output stream\n");
      else perror("fwrite");
      freeCrypto();
      return 1;
    }

  } while (1);

  if (1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, buf_cipher, &len)) handleCryptoError();

  if (len && !fwrite(buf_cipher, len, 1, stdout)) {
    if (feof(stderr)) fprintf(stderr, "EOF on output stream\n");
    else perror("fwrite");
    freeCrypto();
    return 1;
  }

  if (1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, sizeof tag, tag)) handleCryptoError();
  if (!fwrite(tag, sizeof tag, 1, stdout)) {
    if (feof(stderr)) fprintf(stderr, "EOF on output stream\n");
    else perror("fwrite");
    freeCrypto();
    return 1;
  }

  fflush(stdout);
  freeCrypto();
  return 0;
}
```

And here is how to decrypt what the above program has encrypted:

(compile this way `gcc -Wall -lcrypto -o aes256gcm-decrypt aes256gcm-decrypt.c`)

```
// AES-256-GCM with libcrypto
// gcc -Wall -lcrypto -o aes256gcm-decrypt aes256gcm-decrypt.c

// tag is 16 bytes long
// no AAD (Additional Associated Data)
// input format: tag is read just after cipher text (see RFC-5116, sections 5.1 and 5.2)

// KEY=a6a7ee7abe681c9c4cede8e3366a9ded96b92668ea5e26a31a4b0856341ed224
// IV=87b7225d16ea2ae1f41d0b13fdce9bba
// cat ciphertext | ./aes256gcm-decrypt $KEY $IV

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = NULL;
unsigned char *iv = NULL;
unsigned char *buf_plain = NULL;
unsigned char *buf_cipher = NULL;
unsigned char *input = NULL;

typedef enum { false, true } bool;

void freeCrypto() {
  if (input) free(input);

  if (ctx) {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    ctx = NULL;
  }
  CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
  ERR_free_strings();

  if (iv) {
    free(iv);
    iv = NULL;
  }
  if (buf_plain) {
    free(buf_plain);
    buf_plain = NULL;
  }
  if (buf_cipher) {
    free(buf_cipher);
    buf_cipher = NULL;
  }
}

void handleCryptoError() {
  fprintf(stderr, "ERROR\n");
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  freeCrypto();
  exit(1);
}

bool isValidHexChar(char c) {
  return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}

unsigned char hex2uchar(char *hex) {
  unsigned char ret;

  if (hex[0] >= 'a' && hex[0] <= 'f') ret = (hex[0] - 'a' + 10) * 16;
  else ret = (hex[0] - '0') * 16;
  if (hex[1] >= 'a' && hex[1] <= 'f') ret += hex[1] - 'a' + 10;
  else ret += hex[1] - '0';
  return ret;
}

unsigned char *loadInput(int *plen) {
  int len = 0;
  unsigned char *buf = NULL;
  unsigned char *old_buf;

  do {
    int c = fgetc(stdin);
    if (c == EOF) break;
    if (c < 0) {
      perror("fgetc");
      exit(1);
    }
    len++;
    old_buf = buf;
    buf = malloc(len);
    if (buf < 0) {
      perror("malloc");
      exit(1);
    }
    if (len > 1) bcopy(old_buf, buf, len - 1);
    buf[len - 1] = c;
    if (old_buf) free(old_buf);
  } while (1);

  *plen = len;
  return buf;
}

int main(int ac, char **av, char **ae)
{
  const EVP_CIPHER *cipher;
  unsigned char key[32];
  int iv_len, len, i;
  unsigned char *current;
  int input_len;

  if (ac != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s KEY IV\n", av[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  char *key_txt = av[1];
  char *iv_txt = av[2];

  input = loadInput(&input_len);
  current = input;

  ERR_load_crypto_strings();

  if (strlen(key_txt) != 2 * sizeof key) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid key size\n");
    freeCrypto();
    return 1;
  }

  if (strlen(iv_txt) < 2 || strlen(iv_txt) % 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid IV size\n");
    freeCrypto();
    return 1;
  }
  iv_len = strlen(iv_txt) / 2;

  if (!(iv = malloc(iv_len))) {
    perror("malloc");
    freeCrypto();
    return 1;
  }

  if (!(buf_plain = malloc(iv_len))) {
    perror("malloc");
    freeCrypto();
    return 1;
  }

  if (!(buf_cipher = malloc(iv_len))) {
    perror("malloc");
    freeCrypto();
    return 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof key; i++) {
    if (!isValidHexChar(key_txt[2*i]) || !isValidHexChar(key_txt[2*i+1])) handleCryptoError();
    key[i] = hex2uchar(key_txt + 2*i);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < iv_len; i++) {
    if (!isValidHexChar(iv_txt[2*i]) || !isValidHexChar(iv_txt[2*i+1])) handleCryptoError();
    iv[i] = hex2uchar(iv_txt + 2*i);
  }

  if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleCryptoError();
  if (!(cipher = EVP_aes_256_gcm())) handleCryptoError();
  if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, cipher, NULL, NULL, NULL)) handleCryptoError();
  if (1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, iv_len, NULL)) handleCryptoError();
  if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv)) handleCryptoError();
  if (1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, 16, input + input_len - 16)) handleCryptoError();

  do {
    int nbytes = input + input_len - 16 - current;
    if (nbytes > iv_len) nbytes = iv_len;
    if (!nbytes) break;

    bcopy(current, buf_plain, nbytes);
    current += nbytes;

    if (1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, buf_cipher, &len, buf_plain, nbytes)) handleCryptoError();

    if (len && !fwrite(buf_cipher, len, 1, stdout)) {
      if (feof(stderr)) fprintf(stderr, "EOF on output stream\n");
      else perror("fwrite");
      freeCrypto();
      return 1;
    }

  } while (1);

  // correct tag is checked here
  if (EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, buf_cipher, &len) <= 0) handleCryptoError();

  if (len && !fwrite(buf_cipher, len, 1, stdout)) {
    if (feof(stderr)) fprintf(stderr, "EOF on output stream\n");
    else perror("fwrite");
    freeCrypto();
    return 1;
  }

  fflush(stdout);
  freeCrypto();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks and upvoted; newer OpenSSL versions also seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Using Debian 11 with "1.1.1k-1+deb11u1", I had to add `-lcrypto` at the end of the `gcc` -command. Otherwise I got errors like ```undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free'``` => Use: ```gcc -Wall -o aes256gcm aes256gcm.c -lcrypto``` or ```gcc -Wall -o aes256gcm-decrypt aes256gcm-decrypt.c -lcrypto```