# Is Rfc2898DeriveBytes using HMAC SHA1 still considered "secure enough" for hashing passwords?

Tags: passwords, hash, .net

I've been told by a [CISSP](https://www.isc2.org/cissp/default.aspx) that the .NET class Rfc2898DeriveBytes would not pass a security audit today because it still uses SHA1. It's reliance on SHA1 - even with the iterations - leaves it too vulnerable to brute-force cracking. For my own understanding and for anyone else who stumbles across this question, is Rfc2898DeriveBytes still considered a secure method for hashing passwords? Along the same lines, is HMAC SHA256 with a salt but no iterations sufficient?

For the record, since I've been mandated to use anything other than Rfc2898DeriveBytes and since I know better than to roll my own from scratch, I intend to disassemble Rfc2898DeriveBytes and duplicate the code using SHA256 instead of SHA1.

Comment: The biggest weakness of Rfc2898DeriveBytes is that its implementation is slow, so you can only use a relatively low iteration count.

Comment: @CodesInChaos That's not necessarily a weakness, a slower to generate hash can make brute force attacks and rainbow tables a lot less efficient, especially if you're using different salts for each password.

Comment: @johnc My point is that the .net implementation is slow compared to a good implementation, widening the gap between the defenders performance and the attackers performance. Thus lowering security compared to a defender that uses a good implementation that allows them to choose a higher iteration count.

Comment: The nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation` contains `KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2` which implements exactly the same algorithm as `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, but runs several times faster.  It's usuable just fine outside of asp.net (core or otherwise).  The api is also more convenient, and it adds support for HMAC-SHA-512 and HMAC-SHA-256, which let you additionally slightly decrease the advantage of a gpu cracker.

Comment: Note that in later versions of this class you **can** specify a hash algorithm using specific constructors. Note that it is a bad idea to ask for more than the hash output of bytes from this class *as it will repeat all iterations* and may therefore give advantage to an adversary (besides slowing down your server more than you expect). Also note that SHA-512 is often faster than SHA-256 if implemented in software (note that Intel has created special opcodes for SHA-256, so speeds may vary).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) implements the standard algorithm known as [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) and defined in [RFC 2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2) (hence the name). That algorithm uses a configurable underlying pseudorandom function, which is usually [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code), and HMAC itself relies on a configurable underlying hash function, usually SHA-1. While all of this is configurable, a given implementation might not be as flexible, and, indeed, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` *always* uses HMAC and *always* uses SHA-1 as underlying function for SHA-1.

Nowadays, the people collectively known as "auditors" tend to wail, whine, scream, mock and run in circles when they see anything that involves [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1). This is scientifically unwarranted. **Right now**, among all the published Science, there is not the slightest indication that SHA-1 *when used in HMAC* would be weak. Known weaknesses in SHA-1 are about *collisions* which do not impact HMAC (and these are still theoretical anyway). If some guy with a CISSP insists that SHA-1 actually makes PBKDF2 more vulnerable to brute-force, then that guy should go relearn his lessons.

Nevertheless, switching the SHA-256 is not a bad idea, so if shunning SHA-1 is what it takes to get rid of auditors, so be it.

However, the following must still be said:

- Disassembling then modifying is a rather crude method and tends to lead to unmaintainable code. You could simply start from the actual source code (e.g. from [here](http://dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Security/Cryptography/Rfc2898DeriveBytes@cs/1/Rfc2898DeriveBytes@cs)), or, even more simply (and with a cleaner legal status), reimplement it from scratch. .NET provides a [HMAC/SHA-256 implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256(v=vs.110).aspx); using it to do a PBKDF2 code is not hard.
- Alternatively, you may try to reuse some other existing implementation, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18649357/254279).
- You use PBKDF2 when you want to "hash a password", and not all functions are equal in that respect. A hashing function is any good only insofar as it is expensive for attackers to compute. In that respect, PBKDF2 with SHA-1 or SHA-256 is not the best choice; arguably, PBKDF2 with SHA-512 is a better deal (because existing GPU have a harder time optimizing SHA-512 than SHA-256), but other solutions may be preferable, in particular [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). For more on this subject, read [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage/6415#6415), and more generally [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846).

  This means that while SHA-1 "weaknesses" do not make PBKDF2 weaker, it still is a function that can be very well optimized on GPU, which is, in that case, a problem -- but, and that's the important point here, SHA-256 fares no better.
- In any case, by using a pure C# implementation, you accept that this specifically CPU-intensive will run with the inherent slowdown of that technology, which can be estimated to a factor of 2 to 3 when compared with optimized C code (or assembly). In other words, you give an advantage of 2x or 3x to attackers. Therefore, you might want to use some native code here, not pure C#.

Comment: "when used in HMAC" is a bit misleading in this context. With PBKDF2 the use of HMAC is useless at best (and costs a factor 2 with many implementations, including `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`). The reason why SHA-1 is fine in PBKDF2 is that collisions don't matter against password hashes.

Comment: Thank you. What you said makes sense and fits with what I've found in my research. I think I'm pretty experienced - and have the arrogance to go with it - but when it comes to hashing/cryptography I'm never quite certain when I've crossed the line to idiocy. I definitely don't have the experience - or seniority - to call out the CISSP on his statements. I had found the existing implementation as well and will probably use it as a reference. Some of my concern with the question you pointed to was it's age and how things may have changed since then.